# assets audio player library does not match classes

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle

When I build the project at that time getting an error like this

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
> Duplicate class com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.package-info found in modules jetified-exoplayer-common-2.14.1-runtime (com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-common:2.14.1) and jetified-exoplayer-ui-2.13.2-runtime (com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.13.2)

```
 Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.
```

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3m 31s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `/../android/app/build.gradle` add the following line:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation('com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.14.1')
}
```

Comment: This is the only solution that worked, from all that we tested for days! THANK YOU.